# Java Web Application AWT or Swing?

Tags: java, web, applet

When developing a Java web-based application, is it necessary to use AWT?

I've been researching this question and the answers are confusing. Take for example, Runescape. The user visits the website and can play the game right there. They can also download a desktop application to play the game with.

If I am developing a game application, and my main window is created in a `JFrame` but all of my graphics are processed in a `JPanel` inside the main window, will I be able to implement this inside of a web page without much difficulty in the future? I want my game to be accessible simply by visiting the website and running the application.

Additionally, I've seen people reference "Java Web Start". Will this load the java application inside of the website, or does it install/run Java and execute the program (so if my main function opens a JFrame, it would appear on your taskbar). Perhaps I'm having some confusion between a Java application and a Java applet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ..will I be able to implement this inside of a web page without much difficulty in the future?

No.  The security environment around applets was made much stronger in recent times, but even then, browsers tend to put further hurdles between applets and 'onscreen, loaded applets'.  Chrome is set to remove the plug-in which would normally embed applets and a few other things.

> I want my game to be accessible simply by visiting the website and running the application.
>
> Additionally, I've seen people reference "Java Web Start". ..

Yes, offering a link to a JWS launched `JFrame` will be a lot easier, and a better experience for the end user.

Comment: I was looking to avoid having a separate application start out of the web page, but I appreciate the clarification. I think JavaFX is what I am looking for, however. I've been experimenting and it's really easy to develop with. Additionally, it seems to be much easier to implement in browsers and desktop applications (so I'll be able to let the user decide what they prefer).

Comment: *"it seems to be much easier to implement in browsers"*  That means 'applet'.  See [Why CS teachers should **stop** teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/) for some of the difficulties you'll face.